# Spring Mail inline images doesn't work in Mac Mail

Tags: spring, macos, email

When I use Spring to send mail inline images, I found it doesn't show image in Mac Mail App, but it shows it in web Zimbra. My code is as follows, what's wrong with it?

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
mailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
mailSender.setHost(Consts.MAIL_HOST);
mailSender.setUsername(Consts.MAIL_USER);
mailSender.setPassword(Consts.MAIL_PASSWORD);
MimeMessage msg = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true, "UTF-8");
helper.setFrom(mailSender.getUsername());
InternetAddress[] addresses = InternetAddress.parse("sartisty@gmail.com");
helper.setTo(addresses);
helper.setSubject("test");
helper.setText("<html><body><img src='cid:identifier1234'></body></html>", true);
FileSystemResource res = new FileSystemResource(new File("/Users/yanshuai/widget-ca3dc599-9c30-43de-9a2d-b62903301b59.png"));
helper.addInline("identifier1234", res);
mailSender.send(msg);
```

Comment: I face the same problem. Did you got any solution?